# Diode OR or transistor OR circuit?

Tags: transistors, diodes, converter, 3.3v, 24v

I need a circuit that converts a 3.3V signal into a 24V signal. But I also need to be able to activate the 24V signal using a PCB switch. I can do it in two ways, using a diode OR or using a transistor OR, which one is better? They both look ok in the simulation.

Diode OR:

[image]

Transistor OR:

[image]

EDIT:

After @BruceAbbott comment I'm adding a third simpler option, just short circuit the first transistor Q1:

[image]

V(n002) is the control voltage of the SWCTRL switch.

Comment: I would say it's not possible to answer this question the way it has been asked. There are a number of different ways that one circuit could be judged to be "better" than another. (For example: switching speed, simple bill of materials, able to build a physically small circuit.) What things are most important to your needs here? More importantly -- and it looks like you may have this situation here -- *if you have two different solutions that each meet 100% of your requirements, then by definition neither one is 'better', they're both equally good.*

Comment: ...with that said, I would propose one modification to your diode-OR circuit. I would suggest adding a resistor to ground (10k should work just fine) from your node "InputResistor" to ground. Right now when both our inputs are LOW, there is nothing really pulling that node to ground, and in your simulation you can see that V(q1b) is a little slow to go back to 0V. In practice, if you have high leakage current, then it's possible that V(q1b) might never get to ground. A pull-down resistor will help to fix both problems. Aside from that, both circuits do appear to be good solutions.

Comment: Both circuits seem like overkill. Why not just put the switch across Q1 C-E? What is the voltage and current rating of your switch?

Comment: @Mr.Snrub Precisely, both are good for me but sometimes a new pair of eyes helps ;-) About the pull-down resistor, I have it on my KiCad diagram, just forgot to place it here, anyway for this simulation the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Good point, didn't think about it. You are talking about Q1 from the didodes version, right? Going to simulate it, not sure if Q2 will function ok with a short in place of Q1. No constraints about the switch, didn't chose it yet.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub This circuit works with a 60Hz square wave so no real speed constrains, the BOM quantity is almost identical, I'm preferring simplicity of assembly because I'm soldering this in a hot plate with the help of an air gun.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Just added a third circuit to the question, it looks like it works fine so I guess this is the simpler solution.

Comment: I think I'll go for the third circuit, how can I add some debouncing filtering to the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't get it right the debouncing circuit for circuit version 3 so I guess I'm going to use circuit version 2 (with diodes), it looks like working:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

My filter is not working ok, simulation with 5ms pulses at 20ms, the capacitor doesn't discharge fast enough so the InputBySW voltage keeps rising with each pulse and eventually changing the output value:

[image]

Now I'm trying to figure out how to make it work.

EDIT 2:

Came up with this solution that looks like working:

[image]

Comment: Ho well, just realized I don't know how to do a debouncer without using a schmitt trigger buffer. I want to use just BJTs, diodes and transistors, so back to the drawing board. I'll create a new post if I have questions about this new subject.